# Sort nodes that know their neighbours, but not which side they're on

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Take N nodes (where N >= 3) arranged in a straight line. Each node knows its unique identifier and the identifiers of the two nodes closest to it, but not on which side the two closest nodes are.

If I'm given a collection of objects representing the nodes, how do I sort them so they are in the correct order?

For example, if we have four nodes arranged 1,2,3,4 they can be represented by four objects with attributes (1,2,3) (2,1,3) (3,2,4) & (4,2,3) where the triplets are (node, neighbour1, neighbour2).

I'm going to labour the point a bit here, but it's significant that the nodes do not know which neighbour is which. For example, node 3 knows nodes 2 and 4 are its closest neighbours, but does not know which side each one is on. Hence, the four objects shown above are equivalent to (1,3,2) (2,3,1) (3,4,2) & (4,3,2) and any other valid permutation.

The nodes at the end of the line are obviously problematic as both of their closest neighbours are one the same side - though the node itself is unaware of this.

So given N randomly ordered objects representing the nodes, I'm after an algorithm that sorts the objects so they're in a correct order: i.e. left-to-right or right-to-left are equivalent as the orientation of the nodes is unknown.

Any and all suggestions welcome. Thanks!

BTW - If this turns out to be a "well known" data structures / algorithms problem, I'll (a) kick myself for not being able to find it on-line and (b) be glad that there's (presumably) and equally well known solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by identifying the pairs of two end points. You can do this by identifying pairs of points having the same elements.

**For N > 4**

For example (1,2,3) and (2,1,3) are **neighbouring points at the same end** because they have the same elements. Now which of these is the end point and which one is the neighbour?

For that you can notice that the end point (1 here) shall not be present as a neighbour of any other node, whereas the other node (2 here) will be present as a neighbour of one other node (3 here) **if N > 4**. In fact that other node shall be next to this one.

You can then proceed accordingly.

**If N == 3, then you can sort the elements in any order, in fact 6 ways are possible because all elements are neighbours of one another.**

**For N == 4, your problem gets solved as soon as you identify pairs of end points.**

**Complexity of operation: O(N^2)**

Comment: Finding the end points is certainly a good start, though in the N = 4 example the nodes at the ends are (1,2,3) and (4,2,3) [or (1,3,2) and or (4,3,2)]. The test for end-ness becomes that the node in question must be a neighbour of only one other. Thanks for the hint, much appreciated.

Comment: @Attrisoft You will have to identify (1,2,3), (1,32) as one pair of points towards one end (both have same elements) and (4,2,3),(3,2,4) as other pair of points at other end of the line.

Comment: No worries, I got the idea. Works a treat. Thanks again.